# Does std::array default-initialize or value-initialize?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, c++11

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), `std::array`'s constructor performs default-initialization when an `std::array` is created. However, when I'm doing some test in Visual Studio 12.0, in some circumstances `std::array` seems to be performing value-initialization.

```
std::array<int, 3> arr1;  // gives me some garbage values, as expected
auto arr2 = std::array<int, 3>();  // gives me three 0, value-initialize?
```

Also, when `std::array` is a member of a class, sometimes it has indeterminate values while sometimes it has all zero.

```
class Container {
public:
    Container() ...

    int& operator[](size_t i) { return arr[i]; }    
    size_t size() { return ARR_SIZE; }

private:
    static const size_t ARR_SIZE = 3;
    std::array<int, ARR_SIZE> arr;
};
```

When the constructor is not explicitly defined or `arr` is not in the member initializer list, `arr` contains indeterminate values.

```
Container() {}  // arr has indeterminate values, same for no constructor case
```

When `arr` is in the member initializer list, `arr` contains all zero.

```
Container():
    arr()  // arr contains 0, 0, 0
{}
```

Also, when I write the following code, I get an error.

```
Container() :
    arr{ 0, 1, 2 }
{}
```

> g:\cppconsole\cppconsole\main.cpp(89): error C2797: 'Container::arr': list initialization inside member initializer list or non-static data member initializer is not implemented

Is the code supposed to be valid according to the new standard of C++? If so, is it just my Visual Studio version does not support it?

To have the same effect, I write the following code. Is there any potential problem in the code? Because I'm not sure if the code is correct.

```
Container() :
    arr( decltype(arr){ 0, 1, 2 } )
{}
```

P.S. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::array` is an aggregate, it does not have constructors (and that's intentional). So when default-initialised, it default-initialises its elements. When value-initialised, it value-initialises them.

To analyse your code:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr1;  // gives me some garbage values, as expected
auto arr2 = std::array<int, 3>();  // gives me three 0, value-initialize?
```

`arr1` is default-initialised. `arr2` is copy-initialised from a temporary which was initialised with `()`, i.e. value-initialised.

```
Container() {}
```

This leaves the member `arr` default-initialised.

```
Container():
    arr()  // arr contains 0, 0, 0
{}
```

This initialises `arr` using `()`, which is value-initialisation.

```
Container() :
    arr{ 0, 1, 2 }
{}
```

This is legal C++11, but VS 2013 apparently doesn't support it (its C++11 support is incomplete).

Comment: Regarding aggregate, I have done some test in order to understand your point. I have an aggregate: `Aggregate`. `Aggregate s1;` default-initialises the elements, as you said. `Aggregate s2 {};` value-initialises, no problem. However, `Aggregate s3 = Aggregate();` default-initialises. Why? You said _copy-initialised from a temporary which was initialised with (), i.e. value-initialised_, will value-initialises the internal elements.

Comment: I notice that the above situation happens only when there is an element of class type in the aggregate, such as `std::string` or any user-defined classes. If the aggregate contains only primitive types, `Aggregate s3 = Aggregate();` will value-initialises its internal elements. Why does adding class-type element in an aggregate prevent value-initialisation?

Comment: @DannyYL I'd be inclined to say that is a bug. To the best of my knowledge, a value-initialised class without a user-provided ctor should be zero-initialised (C++14 8.5/8).

Comment: I found that it is the problem of Visual Studio. When I compile the program with the command-line prompt using g++, both (with and without class type) value-initialises.